# What is the domain of this function? (Don't know how to solve it, logarithms...)

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, roots, integral-domain

Please explain how you solved it, thanks.

$f(x)=\sqrt{\log_x2 - \log_2x}$

Comment: thanks for editing, im newb :P

Comment: what do you mean with "solved"? Are you concerned to find $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First $x$ should be positive and $x\ne1$. Moreoer
$$\log_x2-\log_2x=\frac{\log2}{\log x}-\frac{\log x}{\log 2}=\frac{\log^22-\log^2 x}{\log 2\log x}=\frac{(\log2-\log x)(\log2+\log x)}{\log 2\log x}\ge0\\\iff x\in [0,\frac12)\cup(1,2]$$
so the domain of definition is $[0,\frac12)\cup(1,2]$.

Comment: I have the feeling that the function exists for $x$ positive less or equal to $1/2$ and for $x$ greater than $1$ and less  or equal to $2$. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You're not wrong!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does $not$ $being$ $wrong$ means $being$ $right$ ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici lol yes you're not wrong so you're right:-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Going, from definition, to natural logarithms, you have $$f(x)=\sqrt{\log_x2 - \log_2x}=\sqrt{\frac{\log (2)}{\log (x)}-\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}}$$

I am sure you can take from here.